# cannot use the session in non-request rendering operations in grails

Tags: java, session, grails, render, gsp

i am trying to send mails in my application when i tries it says "You cannot use the session in non-request rendering operations
" here is full stacktrace:

1. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You cannot use the session
   in non-request rendering operations

   ```
           at grails.gsp.PageRenderer$PageRenderRequest.getSession(PageRenderer.groovy:211)


           at D__workspace_mks_trunk_grails_app_views_promotion__offerTag_gsp.run(_offerTag.gsp:1)


           at D__workspace_mks_trunk_grails_app_views_general__courseNewsletter_course_gsp.run(_courseNewsletter.course.gsp:17)


           at D__workspace_mks_trunk_grails_app_views_general_courseNewsletter_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(courseNewsletter.gsp:145)


           at D__workspace_mks_trunk_grails_app_views_general_courseNewsletter_gsp.run(courseNewsletter.gsp:200)


           at grails.gsp.PageRenderer.renderViewToWriter(PageRenderer.groovy:140)


           at grails.gsp.PageRenderer.render(PageRenderer.groovy:83)


           at EmailerService.sendEmails(EmailerService.groovy:78)


           at com.mks.email.NewsletterController$_closure9.doCall(NewsletterController.groovy:201)


           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)


           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)


           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


         -->
   ```

and there is _offerTag template where i am using session overthere. whats the problem in using it overthere? that too happening from few days. i have checked revision history there is no changes in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Session is created and maintained on the server for subsequent requests from a particular user-agent (web browser mainly).

Therefore you can't use session if you are not in the context of user request - for example in scheduled job processing or in Bootstrap.groovy.